# NullReference Exception C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datatable, access-modifiers

I am getting the following unhandled exception

> NullReferenceException was unhandled. 
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

and something like warning

> Field 'Project3_MineSweeper.Form3.form2' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Here is the code on my DB.cs

```
public class DB
    {
    ...

    public DataTable GetData()
        {
            string spName = "GetTime";
            Connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spName, Connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Score");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["name"] = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]);
                dr["timeScore"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["timeScore"]);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            Connection.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

And here's the code for Form3.cs

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        //THE WARNING
        private Form2 form2; 
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadData();
        }

        public void loadData()
        {
            //UNHANDLED EXCEPTION HERE
            DataTable dt2 = form2.db.GetData(); 
            dgvScore.DataSource = dt2;
        }

    }
```

Lastly Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public DB db;

        private Form3 form3;
        public Form2()
        {
            db = new DB();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     ...
}
```

What's wrong? And what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Another tip = in Visual Studio hit Ctrl + Alt + E.  Check Thrown for the second option (Common Language Runtime exceptions).  This will force the debugger to stop on the line of code that had the error.  This may become annoying so you may want to turn it back off after you find the issue.  Another option is to step through the code one line at a time until it blows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never initialize form2, which makes it cause a nullreference on this line:

> DataTable dt2 = form2.db.GetData();

You should do something like

> form2 = new Form2();

Depending on where you need it.

```
 public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private Form2 form2; // <--- you never initialize form2
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadData();
        }

        public void loadData()
        {
            //UNHANDLED EXCEPTION HERE
            DataTable dt2 = form2.db.GetData(); 
            dgvScore.DataSource = dt2;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void loadData()
{
     form2 = new Form2();  // add this line to init form2 before using
     DataTable dt2 = form2.db.GetData(); 
     dgvScore.DataSource = dt2;
}
```